# How to achieve "Add to desktop" in Google Chrome functionality in command line?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to create Google App shortcuts with command line parameter ***--load-and-launch-app***. My intention is to have script which will create app shortcuts for multiple sites.

I have this manifest.json from shortuct to Google Play Music, but if I edit it to my custom page, it's not working. Is there some different command to use, or is it simple not possible currently in Chrome? If so is there a place to add feature request for such command line parameter?

Or does somone know an alternative with full chrome app?

Add to desktop is really great functionality, but it's really painful to create the shortcuts manually (if you need to add it to new pc, etc.)

```
{
   "app": {
      "icon_color": "#FF5621",
      "launch": {
         "web_url": "https://play.google.com/music/listen?authuser#/now"
      },
      "linked_icons": [ {
         "size": 16,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_16x16.png"
      }, {
         "size": 32,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_32x32.png"
      }, {
         "size": 48,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_96x96.png"
      }, {
         "size": 64,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_96x96.png"
      }, {
         "size": 96,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_96x96.png"
      }, {
         "size": 128,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_96x96.png"
      }, {
         "size": 256,
         "url": "https://play-music.gstatic.com/fe/c817b6f34e9ba8b2803df9213bccc658/favicon_96x96.png"
      } ]
   },
   "description": "Přístup k více než 35 milionům skladeb na požádání bez reklam. Cokoliv si stáhněte a poslouchejte i bez připojení k síti. Přidejte až 50 000 svých skladeb a poslouchejte je kdekoliv.",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icons/128.png",
      "16": "icons/16.png",
      "256": "icons/256.png",
      "32": "icons/32.png",
      "48": "icons/48.png",
      "64": "icons/64.png",
      "96": "icons/96.png"
   },
   "key": "2HZ3mPKf/kG5Q7oBOeugSfs4rKcBvUy6o+msiKPGJS0=",
   "name": "Google Music",
   "version": "2016.11.11.24057"
}
```

Comment: No such feature in chrome api as of now. The supported methods are found in [Add and open Chrome apps](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can't. I use an Acer Chromebook 15 and all putting things on the desktop does is remove it from the "shelf" at the bottom.